# Neo4j 2.3.0 cypher query logging settings and performance tweaks

Tags: neo4j, profiling, cypher, database-performance, neo4jclient

Need to enable query logging for all my Neo4j queries. Not able to find a link for the specific version.

Is there any performance benchmarking tool where we can see the slow queries and the areas that need to be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

In Enterprise edition, you can log slow queries:

http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.4/configuration-settings.html#config_dbms.querylog.enabled

You can also PROFILE queries by putting the keyword PROFILE in front of the query and looking at the query plan.